# Polar decomposition theorem for symplectic and orthogonal Banach Lie groups in infinite dimensional settings

Tags: functional-analysis, lie-groups, operator-theory

Could you please help me to understand the polar decomposition theorem for $Sp(H, J_Q)$ and $O(H,J_R)$ where $H$ is infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $J_R$ and $J_Q$ stands for conjugation and anticonjugation operators such that:
$$O(H,J_R)=\{T \in GL(H):<Tx,J_R(Ty)>=<x,J_Ry>\}$$
$$Sp(H,J_Q)={T \in GL(H):<Tx,J_Q(Ty)>=<x,J_Qy>}.$$

(Note that $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary vectors in $H$).

Comment: MO is not the place to ask for tutorials on subjects.  The way your question is phrased, you are simply asking other people to work for you.  Try to come up with a concrete question.  What is it precisely that you are confused about?

Comment: Let T be an operator in Sp(H,J_Q) then I want to show that T can be decomposed as a product of two operators such that the first one is symplectic and unitary and the other one is symplectic and positive. This is definitely true for the decomposition of GL(H) that is polar decomposition theorem.